# javascript call function after dropping a dragged element

Tags: javascript, html, events, drag-and-drop

I have some simple draggable html code that allows users to reorder table rows.  It all works, but I need to execute a final script after the user drops the dragged row and can't figure out how to do it.  At this point, I need to call the function `rowOrderWrite()` when the user drops the element and then pass the tableID to that function.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Head1</th>
       <th>Head2</th>
       <th>Head3</th>
       <th>Head4</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr id="row1" draggable="true" ondragstart="rowOrderStart()" ondragover="rowOrderEnd()">
       <td>values 1</td>
       <td>values 2</td>
       <td>values 3</td>
       <td>values 4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="row2" draggable="true" ondragstart="rowOrderStart()" ondragover="rowOrderEnd()">
       <td>values 5</td>
       <td>values 6</td>
       <td>values 7</td>
       <td>values 8</td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="row3" draggable="true" ondragstart="rowOrderStart()" ondragover="rowOrderEnd()">
       <td>values 8</td>
       <td>values 9</td>
       <td>values 10</td>
       <td>values 11</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And my JS:

```
  var row;

  function rowOrderStart(){  
    row = event.target; 
  }
  function rowOrderEnd(){
    var e = event;
    e.preventDefault(); 
    let children= Array.from(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children);
    
    if(children.indexOf(e.target.parentNode)>children.indexOf(row))
      e.target.parentNode.after(row);
    else
      e.target.parentNode.before(row);

    var tableID = e.target.parentNode.id ;
  }

  function rowOrderWrite(tableID){
     // do stuff with reorder table rows
     ...
  }
```

Comment: Use `ondragend`?

Comment: @ChrisG - I somehow looked right over this...several times.  Thanks.  I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChrisG responded with....the solution is to use `ondragend(functionName);` - I somehow overlooked this (multiple times).